# Imporperly closed questions

Tags: discussion

Can someone explain to me why my question was closed: [Troubleshooting Magento 1.9.2.4 with PHP 7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122919/troubleshooting-magento-1-9-2-4-with-php-7)

The linked answer doesn't help anyone resolve the issue I outlined and the selected "answer" isn't even for the right version of Magento.

People aren't reading, they are just clicking to close votes. If I look at the history of the people who voted to close (I wont link accounts) but the action is always Close, Close, Close.

I voted to re-open but quite frankly I am getting fed up.

Comment: It's reopened now.

Comment: You are #1 @Marius - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're very sorry that this keeps happening. We're working hard to combat this problem on Magento.SE.

The question (which was linked as a duplicate) was removed from the comment history. This is the question which was **incorrectly** marked as a duplicate:

[Is Magento ready for PHP 7?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74008/is-magento-ready-for-php-7)

This question is problematic and has been the focus of a number of Magento / PHP7 false duplicates. The close votes tend to pile on, especially quickly when it comes to "duplicate" questions - and so we're actively monitoring for this.

We're watching Meta closely - and Marius caught this very quickly:

From Marius in his reopen:

> This is not a duplicate - people can't read! Please remove this flag as it will actually be incorrectly closed. Others have had this issue and it has nothing to do with the link provided.

### A way forward

Just so you know this is a problem I've taken upon myself to drive the community and moderator team to resolving. I have opened many meta threads to address just this issue. Here is a blog by Fabian recapping our MageStackDay panel:

https://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2016/06/magestackday-5-and-the-moderation-discussion/

And here's the panel discussion when I expanded on my thoughts that as a community we need to do better on Magento.SE:

https://youtu.be/uthuA56x6Es

Comment: I very much appreciate the thorough answer and that there is a plan to monitor this type of situation. This community is growing and with it comes issues and I'm happy that you and the moderation team have a handle / pulse on it.

Comment: I just had a look at those links, I have to say you guys are awesome, I had absolutely no idea of how much time you guys have been putting in; please accept my apologies for the tone of my comments, I have a new appreciation for what you guys have done / are doing for this community.

Comment: Not a problem. You are one of the helpful people here - please don't get discouraged. Feel free to reach out to me directly when you feel that things are frustrating.

Comment: Again much appreciated :)